# Different graph after converting tflearn model to keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tflearn

I have the following code written using tflearn:

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import fully_connected, input_data
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression


def model():
    network = input_data(shape=[None, 5, 1], name='input')
    print('network:', network)
    # Outputs: network: Tensor("input/X:0", shape=(?, 5, 1), dtype=float32)
    network = fully_connected(network, 25, activation='relu')
    print('fully_network_1:', network)
    # Outputs: fully_network_1: Tensor("FullyConnected/Relu:0", shape=(?, 25), dtype=float32)
    network = fully_connected(network, 1, activation='linear')
    print('fully_network_2:', network)
    # Outputps: fully_network_2: Tensor("FullyConnected_1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
    network = regression(network, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=self.lr,
                         loss='mean_square', name='target')
    print('reg:', network)
    # Outputs: reg: Tensor("FullyConnected_1/BiasAdd:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)
    model = tflearn.DNN(network, tensorboard_dir='log', tensorboard_verbose=3)
    return model
```

The created model is trained using the following code:

```
def train_model(train_x, train_y, model):
    train_x = train_x.reshape(-1, 5, 1)
    train_y = train_y.reshape(-1, 1)
    print(train_x.shape)
    # Outputs: (599068, 5, 1)
    print(train_y.shape)
    # Outputs: (599068, 1)
    model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=3, shuffle=True, run_id='model.tflearn')
    model.save('model.tflearn')
```

When I display the graph using Tensorboard, I get the following graph:

[image]

I wanted to migrate to Tensorflow 2.2.0 (from Tensorflow 1.15.0), so I decided to rewrite the previous code using Tensorflow2, here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf


def build_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=25, activation='relu',
                                    input_shape=(5, 1)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9,
                                   beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
                                   amsgrad=False, name='Adam')
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse')
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

The model summary returns:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 5, 25)             50        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5, 1)              26        
=================================================================
Total params: 76
Trainable params: 76
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

The created model is trained using the following code:

```
import datetime
import tensorflow as tf


def train(model, train_x, train_y):
    train_x = train_x.reshape(-1, 5, 1)
    train_y = train_y.reshape(-1, 1)
    # train_x.shape = (599068, 5, 1)
    # train_y.shape = (599068, 1)
    log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

    model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=3, verbose=1, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
    model.save_weights('model.h5')
```

When I display the model's graph I got this:

[image]

This is totally different from the graph I got with tflearn.
Did I miss something when building the model with Tensorflow?

**Notice:** I got different losses when I train both models, the first model's loss is 0.06, while the model built with Tensorflow2 has 0.25 as loss, which is far from the first one!